# How to make UrlRewrite to change my address?

Tags: java, url-rewriting

Need to get rid of *jsessionid* from my url. After some research on the internet a found out that UrlRewrite can do that.

So I created a rule for it. Here is the xml file (urlrewrite.xml) :

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <name>Strip SessionID</name>
        <note>Strip all URLs of Session ID</note>
        <from>^(.*)(;jsessionid=[a-zA-Z0-9]{32})(.*)$</from>
        <to encode="false">$1$3</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

The problem is it does not quite work. Is my rule correct ?

I tried debuging a bit. And I used this rule:

```
<rule>
  <name>Strip SessionID</name>
  <note>Strip all URLs of Session ID</note>
  <from>initialPage.jsp</from>
  <to encode="false">redirectPage.jsp</to>
</rule>
```

Going to the browser and entering **http://localhost:8080/initialPage.jsp** and hitting enter (of course) I get a big surprize. It works.

I get redirected to **redirectPage.jsp**. I mean I see that page.

*But here is the trick* : the url in the address bar of the browser has not changed.

How, in the world, does this UrlRewrite help me get rid of *jsessionid* if I still see it there ? Any ideas ? How to configure a rule to help me NOT see that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve. To get rid of `jsessionid` you need to process URLs generated by your application, not the incoming URLs, therefore you need to specify `<outbound-rule>`, see the corresponding example [here](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/3.0/guide.html).

Regarding the seciond snippet - by default `UrlRewriteFilter` *forwards* your request to the new address, not *redirects* it, so address bar remains the same. You can configure it to redirect your request by using `<to type = "redirect">`.

Comment: thx. it was not clear in my head what each rule was for... plus the other thing, too :P

Answer (score 0):

On a similar quest some months back, I had come across [this article](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/RemovingJSESSIONIDFromYourURLsAndFixingScache) - it helped me to get rid of the niggling problem posed by the *jsessionid* parameter in the URL.